# powershell the let's encrypt extension for Azure web app

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-powershell

I have scripts to install the extension, add the app settings but actually requesting and installing a cert is still a manual process through the kudu website. I'm not even sure exactly what to search for, or if it's possible. But what I'd like to do is create a script that requests and installs the certificate for each hostname on an app, just as if I were clicking through the screens in kudu.

Answer (score 3):

I believe I wrote just the tool for you:
https://github.com/ohadschn/letsencrypt-webapp-renewer.

**EDIT** - Specifically for PowerShell, I found this (never tested it though): https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Register-LetsEncryptCertificate/1.0/DisplayScript.

Comment: Thanks! Darn, forgot to save my comment earlier. Your script looks like it just renews the certificates, does it handle initial registration and install? The Let's Encrypt Extension creates a webjob to handle renewals after the cert is successfully created and installed. I'm able to walk through the wizard and order the certs, but it's a mind numbing manual process and I have hundreds of domains ... Trying to complete a project to get SSLs on ALL sites as part of a security control.

I also tried the script but can't find much documentation on it and couldn't get it to work :(

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by registration and install. You just need a service principal that's authorized as an admin on the subscription / resource groups containing the web apps you want to renew. There's no difference between initial cert creation and renewal - they both just create a new cert and assign it to your Web App. If I were you, I'd install my WebJob on a dedicated Web App and configure all my sites there. You could even deploy it using an ARM template with all the settings: http://blogs.perficient.com/microsoft/2016/03/azure-arm-template-define-web-app-application-settings/.

Comment: To get the cert installed and bound to the app I have to go through the wizard found for the extension found in the kudu site. I configured all the app settings and made sure the web job was running, but the extension never installs the cert. Maybe I missed something. Manual install works. This is what I was doing for reference. 

3. Request and Install a Certificate on this site:
https://gooroo.io/GoorooTHINK/Article/16420/Lets-Encrypt-Azure-Web-Apps-the-Free-and-Easy-Way/20047

Comment: @MikeKauspedas using my WebJob (or command-line) you don't need the extension at all, that's the whole point. It replaces it. Instead of installing the extension in hundreds of Web Apps, you install my WebJob in one (preferably dedicated) Web App and configure it to renew all your sites.